# After running `brew upgrade` in macOS 14.3, I got this error while installing numpy: 'Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully...'

Tags: macos, homebrew, python, zsh, symlink

The full error message is:

```zsh
==> Pouring numpy--1.26.3.arm64_sonoma.bottle.1.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /opt/homebrew
Could not symlink bin/f2py
Target /opt/homebrew/bin/f2py
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/opt/homebrew/bin/f2py'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite numpy

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run numpy

Possible conflicting files are:
```

followed by a long list of files, most of which are located in `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/`. I tried executing `brew link numpy`, but received the error message:

```zsh
Linking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/numpy/1.26.3...
Error: Could not symlink bin/f2py
Target /opt/homebrew/bin/f2py
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/opt/homebrew/bin/f2py'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite numpy

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run numpy
```

I ran `brew link --overwrite --dry-run numpy`, and Homebrew output the same long list of files as before.

Does anyone know if removing all of those files, in the hopes that I can successfully link numpy, would work without causing any problems on my system? I use the numpy library in my development work, so I definitely need it.

Edit: Output of `ls -laG /opt/homebrew/bin/f2py`:

```zsh
-rwxr-xr-x     1 clark  wheel    244 Jan 11 13:15 f2py
-rwxr-xr-x     1 clark  wheel    242 Nov 14 19:14 f2py3
-rwxr-xr-x     1 clark  wheel    242 Nov 14 19:14 f2py3.9
```

Apparently, f2py and its variants don't point to anything.

Comment: What does `/opt/homebrew/bin/f2py` point at already? Can you [edit] with the output of `ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/f2py` please?

Comment: Did you try to install `numpy`  with pip?  If you did with a Homebrew `python`, I could see you ending up with this problem.  There was something in the Homebrew fora not too long ago about someone who'd tried to mix homebrew-packaged with normal python packages.

Comment: Well, after a `--dry-run`, of course nothing changes. This is the purpose of a **dry** run. Don't use this option if you want to fix the problem.